# Angular option select show hide Angular repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I hope I can explain this in a easy way:

I have the following code

```
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="bankDetail in profile.bankDetails" value="{{bankDetail.bankDetailNumber}}"> {{bankDetail.bankName}}</option>
</select>`

<div ng-repeat="bankDetail in profile.bankDetails">
      {{bankDetailName}}
</div>
```

According to the value selected in the dropdown I want to show and hide the second div.

For the life of me I can't find any example of this type of code.

Currently it is showing all of the values in the second div, I want the first one to show and then hide/show the rest depending on the drop down input change.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use something like:

```
<select ng-model="selectModel">
  <option ng-repeat="bankDetail in profile.bankDetails" ng-value="{{bankDetail.bankDetailNumber}}"> {{bankDetail.bankName}}</option>
</select>`

<div ng-repeat="bankDetail in profile.bankDetails"
     ng-if="selectModel === bankDetailName">
      {{bankDetailName}}
</div>
```

The thing works like that, if the select value is the same with the `bankDetailName` (I think you have something like `bankDetail.name` not `bankDetailName`) then display the div.

Instead of `ng-if` you can use `ng-show`.

Comment: Yes so yours work with a few tweaks, but in a fiddle yours works from the start. Thanks man. Appreciate your help and effort.

Comment: I havent test the code, but thats the right way to do this

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
<select ng-model="selection" ng-init="selection=profile.bankDetails[0]">
  <option ng-repeat="bankDetail in profile.bankDetails" ng-value="bankDetail"> {{bankDetail.bankName}}</option>
</select>`

<div>
   {{selection.bankName}}
</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I looking for, I tried a similar solution but it does not want to work on my side, and It also adds an extra blank record into the drop down box.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for our problem.

Try this below fiddle and you will find your solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19314/

You have to use ng-options in this case as I have used.

```
 <select ng-model="selection" ng-options="obj as obj.Name for obj in someArray">
```

`

Let me know if you find any difficulty in this. Would love to help.

Comment: @theunis You can substitute your array in place of "someArray" and then you are good to go.